# python 3 try/except exiting rather than looping

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm trying to limit user input to 1-6 (dice game).  The logic is working but when a ValueError() is raised it doesn't prompt the user again.

```
try:
    while True:
        choice = input('Enter number to hold - type D to roll: ')
        print(choice)
        if choice == 'D':
            return choice_list
        elif len(choice) > 1 or choice not in '12345':
            raise ValueError()
        else:
            choice_list[int(choice) - 1] = 'X'
            printer(roll_list, choice_list)
except ValueError:
    print ("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're exiting your loop at `Exception`. You should write a code like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        choice = input('Enter number to hold - type D to roll: ')
        print(choice)
        if choice == 'D':
            return choice_list
        elif len(choice) > 1 or choice not in '12345':
            raise ValueError()
        else:
            choice_list[int(choice) - 1] = 'X'
            printer(roll_list, choice_list)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid input")
```

Comment: Thanks - very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop before try code which will keep looping try and catch block like this

```
while True:
   try:
     # Your Code

   except ValueError:
     # Your Code
```